# Stored procedure updating same value for al the records

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

```
create table test_staging(value varchar2(30));
insert into test_staging values('A');
insert into test_staging values('B');
insert into test_staging values('C');
insert into test_staging values('D');

create sequence test_main_sq;
create table test_main(id number,value varchar2(30));

create or replace procedure p_test
as
begin
v_sql := 'TRUNCATE TABLE test_main';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql;

insert into test_main(value)
select value from test_staging;

for i in(select value from test_staging)
loop
update test_main set id = (select max(rownum) from test_staging) - 1;
end loop;
end;
/

Database: Oracle Live SQL (19c)
```

Problem statement:

I want to insert records from staging table into the main table but `id` column of main table should be updated in reversed order e.g last record of staging table should have `id` column value as 1, second last as 2, and so on. So the first record of the main table should have maximum id.

Expected rows of test_main table:

```
+----+-------+
| id | value |
+----+-------+
|  4 | A     |
|  3 | B     |
|  2 | C     |
|  1 | D     |
+----+-------+
```

But as per my logic, it is updating 3 for all the Id's.

Comment: "updating same value for al the records" - that's because there's no WHERE clause in UPDATE statement, so each execution updates all rows over and over again. Anyway, that's most probably wrong way of doing it; see what dr said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this for insert:

```sql
Select 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Order By VALUE Desc) "RN",
    VALUE "VAL"
From test_staging;
```

| RN | VAL |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | D |
| 2 | C |
| 3 | B |
| 4 | A |

There is no need for updating IDs when you can insert them along with values. Your sql within the update loop returns 3 for every record becouse the Select Max(ROWNUM) From test_staging is a fixed value of 4. You can just put it all in one insert command:

```sql
Insert Into test_main(ID, VALUE)
Select 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Order By VALUE Desc) "RN",
    VALUE "VAL"
From test_staging;
```

I used ROW_NUMBER() analytic function. More about it (and the others) at: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions004.htm#SQLRF06174
Regards...